# How to expose services in private AKS cluster?

Tags: networking, azure, kubernetes, aks

I've created a private cluster on AKS and deployed some workloads to it, but I'm not sure how to connect to the services. They are all NodePort services, both TCP & UDP.

Initially, I thought that the endpoint AKS provides could be used to interact with the cluster as a whole, but this isn't the case -- this only exposes the Kubernetes API (probably why they call it the API endpoint)

I also tried using the VMSS public IP but that didn't work either. Using the instance IP works, but the IPs would change over time, right?

Ultimately I decided to use an ingress controller and proxy the traffic, but because I'm using mixed protocols I would need two. Not to mention this seems too complex to be the reasonable solution to this problem.

How to expose services on a private AKS cluster? This should be a pretty common problem, I think, but I haven't found a clear solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever finds themselves in this situation, we ended up using ExternalDNS and a private zone, since we're using NodePorts anyways.

This gives us a stable endpoint which will be automatically updated if one of the node's IPs ever changes.

Something to note is that the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md#creating-service-principal) implies no role assignment over the subscription is needed (By default, create-for-rbac grants `Contributor` on the subscription to the service principal which [--skip-assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_sp_create_for_rbac) avoids) but this didn't work for me, ExternalDNS got permission denied when trying to read the private zones.

I tried some different combinations but ended up giving `Private DNS Zone Contributor` on the subscription and skipping any assignments to the zone and resource group.

Also want to point out a gotcha, there are two providers for Azure, `azure` for public DNS and `azure-private-dns` for private DNS, and they differ slightly in configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Thank you for sharing the solution you discovered for your question. Please accept your answer to prevent your question from cycling through SE-enforced merry-go-round of active questions.